# Java how to using Regex mask numberic as I expected

Tags: java, regex

Suggest I have follow two values:

```
       123456789
       123456789111
```

Does String.replaceAll can do follow?

```
       123456789           ->    XXXXXX789
       123456789111        ->    XXXXXXXXX111
```

for mask last three numberic, but replace other characters to X?  Please noted the count of X in sample.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, replaceAll function will do this job.

```
String s1 = "123456789";
String s2 = "123456789111";
System.out.println(s1.replaceAll("\\d(?=\\d{3})", "X"));
System.out.println(s2.replaceAll("\\d(?=\\d{3})", "X"));
```

**Output:**

```
XXXXXX789
XXXXXXXXX111
```

**Explanation:**

- `\\d(?=\\d{3})` Match a digit only if it's followed by three digits. So it fails for last three digits. Finally all the matched digits are replaced by the letter `X`

Answer (score 1):

```
.(?!.{0,2}$)
```

Try this.Replace by `X`.Put flags `m` and `g`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sK8oK9/2

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "123456789";
    String s2 = "123456789111";
    String regex = "\\d(?=\\d{3})"; // each digit followed by exactly 3 digits should be replaced by X
    System.out.println(s1.replaceAll(regex, "X"));
    System.out.println(s2.replaceAll(regex, "X"));

}
```

O/P :

```
XXXXXX789
XXXXXXXXX111
```